# How do I fix my text to make it appear on one line?

Tags: javascript, html, text, hyperlink, format

I would like my text to say "Like us on Facebook for the chance to win a prize." I want the word "Facebook" linked but not underlined. I also want the text and link to be on one line. [Here is what the output looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8asU.png)

Here is my code.

```
function popupWin() {
text =  "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Pop Window</title>\n<body>\n";
text += "<center>\n<br>";
text += "<h4>Like us on </h4>" + "<a href='myLink' target='_blank'><h4>Facebook</h4></a>" + " <h4>and win a prize</h4>";
text += "</center>\n</body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout('windowProp(text)', 1000); 
}
function windowProp(text) {
newWindow = window.open('','newWin','width=300,height=200');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}
```

Comment: Each `<h4>` is a block. You don't need three, you probably want one with the content inside.

Comment: And to make it not underlined, you'd want `text-decoration: none;` on the `<a>`

Answer (score 2):

```
function popupWin() {
text =  "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Pop Window</title>\n<body>\n";
text += "<center>\n<br>";
text += "<h4>Like us on " + "<a href='myLink' target='_blank' style='text-decoration: none;'>Facebook</a>" + " and win a prize</h4>";
text += "</center>\n</body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout('windowProp(text)', 1000); 
}
function windowProp(text) {
newWindow = window.open('','newWin','width=300,height=200');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}

popupWin();
```

One `<h4>` tag is sufficient to make whole text h4. You don't need to multiplicate it.

For not underlining Facebook link is responsible CSS `text-decoration: none` in an inline html attribute `style`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function popupWin() {
      text =  "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Pop Window</title>\n<body>\n";
      text += "<center>\n<br>";
      text += "<h4 style="display:inline">Like us on </h4>" + "<a href='myLink' target='_blank' style="text-decoration:none; display:inline">    <h4 style="display:inline">Facebook</h4></a>" + " <h4 style="display:inline"> and win a prize</h4>";
      text += "</center>\n</body>\n</html>\n";
      setTimeout('windowProp(text)', 1000); 
}
```

Should work!

`display:inline` makes the elements come in one line

`text-decoration:none` removes all the extra stuff like the underline.

Comment: Or you can just make one <h4> tag. <h4>Like us on <a href="mylink" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">Facebook</a> and win prizes</h4>

Answer (score 0):

Better styling it with css file. In your case, in order to remove the underline, you can set an id for the Facebook div, and style text-decoration to none. Additionally, to make it appear in one line, you can use either float:left or display:inline. You can use float:left because it'll turn block element into inline element. Like Below

JS:

```
function popupWin() {
text =  "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Pop Window</title>\n<body>\n";
text += "<center>\n<br>";
text += "<h4>Like us on</h4>" + "<h4><a href='myLink' target='_blank' id="facebook" Facebook</a></4>" + "<h4>and win a prize</h4>";
text += "</center>\n</body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout('windowProp(text)', 1000); 
}
function windowProp(text) {
newWindow = window.open('','newWin','width=300,height=200');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}
```

CSS:

```
#facebook {
   text-decoration: none;
}
h4 {
   float:left // or display:inline
}
```

P/S: Or you can just remove all unnecessary h4 tag, since each h4 is a block element, so it'll automatically make new like when new h4 tag is made. so if you use only one h4 tag, it'll not make a new line. Just like above answer.